# "How is going" or "How is it going" or both?

Tags: sentence-usage

Which one is correct? "How is going" or "How is it going". I googled it but it seemed both are in use. Am I right with this point?

Comment: I'd like to see you elaborate a little on finding them both in use. (The first one is not in use, insofar as I know.)

Comment: Since there are Chinese bloggers explaining these two, so I am not sure about whether they are wrong or these two sentences are in use. :)

Comment: Including some excerpts and links in your question would make this a more interesting question. It would probably also help those who might want to attempt to answer.

Comment: I _do_ see mainly Chinese(?) using the word. If the first handful of Google hits on an English sentence are Chinese, chances are the phrase is _not_ (commonly) used by native speakers of English.

Comment: "Who is going to lead the invasion of New York?" King George asked. "Howe is going," his aide replied.

Answer (score 11):

```
How is it going?
```

is the correct form, although it is usually abbreviated to `How's it going?`  Dropping the `it` from the sentence makes it unclear what is being asked.